# Showing white image as grey on white background: Android

Tags: android, image, alpha

I have an image that is a white square. I would like to convert it to a grey image on a white background. I think alpha could be used here but i am not sure.

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: i don't have a cod. As i am not sure how to do this.

Comment: i posted the image but it is white in color so cant see it

Comment: Can you make your posted image appear grey so we can see it?  (joking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you can use setColorFilter() method of image view to set a filter/tint for your imageview.
sample-

```
  imageView.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY);

 imageView.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY,PorterDuff.Mode.Lighten);
```

the second one gives a tinted effect.